# _DoPostBack is undefined not previously answered but related to routing

Tags: asp.net, webforms, routes, dopostback

First, I've studied the _doPostBack is undefined error extensively. I'm aware that .NET 4.0 and earlier versions of .NET didn't include all the proper definitions for recognizing newer browsers. I am running .NET 4.5 and the nature of this error doesn't seem to be explained in any of the other questions regarding this issue.

Under .NET 4.5 and IE 11 with custom routing, I get the _doPostback is undefined on a page with a single button, no master page. However, when I turn off the custom routing, I no longer get the error. Now bizarrely, when I turn the routing back on then it will continue to work "for some time" and then the error shows back up. I have also reboot the computer and continue to get the error until I turn off the routing.

I have rebuild my solution and closed all browsers. I have a route that is a catch all that may be causing the problem. However, again when I remove custom routing, it fixes the issue. When I re-add the custom routing, it works for a time but then it later it fails randomly.

Update, I also see strange postback behavior when running under Chrome. With the "catch all" route enabled, the client-side validators don't seem to work but intead the page is posted back to the server and then validated.

The generic route is defined last in my list of routes but doesn't seem to make any difference. It is designed as such

> routes.MapPageRoute("DefaultRoute", "{Company}/{*queryvalues}",
>   "~/default.aspx");

What's interesting is this bug impacts routes that are more specific and defined before this route.

**Update** 
I was asked to post the routing rules. The last rule is the one that caused the problems. The website is designed to support a number of clients. I had thought that sense I had more specific matching rules added before that they would function properly. However, for some reason, the catch all route still causes problems. The easiest solution is to change it to a named route but it is not as elegant. The previous structure for this website used virtual directories for the Client portion.

```
RouteValueDictionary dynamicEventDefaults = new RouteValueDictionary();
                       dynamicEventDefaults.Add("Client", "");
                       dynamicEventDefaults.Add("EventId", "0");
routes.MapPageRoute("EventRoute", {Client}/Event/{EventId}/{*queryvalues}","~/DynamicEvent.aspx",
                       false, dynamicEventDefaults);

routes.MapPageRoute("DefaultRoute", "{Client}/{*queryvalues}", "~/default.aspx");
```

Comment: Have you tried this under other browsers and versions? Do you get the same error? How about on different client machines?

Comment: @Jim Very strange... under Chrome, I don't get/see an error but when I  put a button with text box and validator on it, I get a strange behavior. Instead of validating client side, the page is posted back and then validated. This does not happen in IE 11. When I disable the routing, the page validates client side normally.

Comment: Another question: where is your ScriptManager set up?  It's feeling a bit like there's some sort of funky JavaScript being created by .Net that's getting confused by something specific to how you are using it (if so, it's likely not your fault). If this is the case, the answer may need to lie in trying to tweak things related to JavaScript to see if they un-funkify it.

Comment: Can you post your routing rules/config, perhaps some sample routed URLs? Perhaps tweaking something in the structure of your routing will make the problem go back underground.

Comment: Since you're getting different behaviors from IE and Chrome, another idea: can you now also test under Firefox to "break the tie" and see which weird behavior seems more consistent? That could then be the thread to focus on for further investigative efforts.

Comment: JimMSDN Well, again the behavior in Chrome is that the Javascript wasn't executed where in IE it worked for a while and then it quit working. This behavior should be reproceable with the small amount of code I've included.